# A better way of validating fields in JAVA

Tags: java, validation, if-statement

I'm making a booking system for a school project. In it, I need to validate some fields and was wondering if there is a better/more efficient way of implementing this.

Example inputs:

```
String firstName = "Alex";
String surname = "Smith";
int numberOfGuests = 3;
int numberOfPets = 2;
String email = "alexSmith@gmail.com";
```

Validation:

```
final int GUEST_MIN = 1;
int guestMax = 4;
final int PETS_MIN = 0;
int petsMax = 4;
boolean presenceCheck = false;
boolean rangeCheck = false;
boolean formatCheck = false;

//Presence Check
if(!(firstName.isEmpty() || surname.isEmpty() || email.isEmpty()))
{
    presenceCheck = true;
}
System.out.println(presenceCheck);

//RangeCheck
if(!(numberOfGuests < GUEST_MIN || numberOfGuests > guestMax || numberOfPets < PETS_MIN || numberOfPets > petsMax))
{
    rangeCheck = true;
}
System.out.println(rangeCheck);

//Format Check
if(email.contains("@"))
{
    formatCheck = true;
}
System.out.println(formatCheck);
```

I plan to add to this and was wondering if there is a way of avoiding many lines of if statments.

Comment: If you need to make use of the same validation repeatedly, you can either make the individual tests into functions or else make a class to contain your data that validates the properties as you set them.  In the end, every test will be rooted in an if statement.

Comment: is javax validation overkill for a school project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some issues with your validation as well.

What if the string is `null`? What is the string is `"  "`?

For `presenceCheck`, it's better to write a function:

```
public static boolean empty(List<String> strings) {
    // Null-safe, short-circuit evaluation.
    // .trim() removes the whitespace from front and back
    // if anyString is null or empty or space, it will return true, else false
    return strings.stream().anyMatch(s -> s == null || s.trim().isEmpty());
}
```

Then you can call it like:

```
presenceCheck = empty(Arrays.asList(firstName, lastName, email);
```

There is no better solution for your rangeCheck. Except removing the if like this:

```
rangeCheck = (!(numberOfGuests < GUEST_MIN || numberOfGuests > guestMax || numberOfPets < PETS_MIN || numberOfPets > petsMax));
```

Just checking for `@` in email is not enough, you should do something like:

```
public static final Pattern VALID_EMAIL_ADDRESS_REGEX = 
    Pattern.compile("^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Z]{2,6}$", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

public static boolean validateEmail(String emailStr) {
    return VALID_EMAIL_ADDRESS_REGEX.matcher(emailStr).find();
}

formatCheck = validateEmail(email);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the intention is to reduce the lines then directly assign boolean output to the variables as below.

```
presenceCheck = (!(firstName.isEmpty() || surname.isEmpty() || email.isEmpty()));

rangeCheck = (!(numberOfGuests < GUEST_MIN || numberOfGuests > guestMax || numberOfPets < PETS_MIN || numberOfPets > petsMax));

formatCheck = (email.contains("@"));
```

If you wish to use ternary operator for more clarity, use as below.

```
    presenceCheck = (!(firstName.isEmpty() || surname.isEmpty() || email.isEmpty())) ? true:false; 
    rangeCheck = (!(numberOfGuests < GUEST_MIN || numberOfGuests > guestMax || numberOfPets < PETS_MIN || numberOfPets > petsMax)) ? true : false; 
formatCheck = (email.contains("@"))? true :false;
```

Comment: Where is the ternary operator? How is this an improvement over what is already there?

Comment: No ternary but one of the asks was to reduce all the if statements so the above answer is a significant improvement in terms of the requirements.

Comment: Then please don't mention ternary in the answer is your answer does not use it.

Comment: @HarshalParekh, i have corrected my original comment. Added another comment with ternary operator

Comment: You should add it in your answer and not in comments

Comment: @HarshalParekh -Done.